# Cannot remove empty space between rows

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want to export the report to *html* format and set some configuration with `SimpleHtmlReportConfiguration`. The `exporter.setConfiguration(reportConfig)` not working. I don't know.

My old code:

```
HtmlExporter exporter = new HtmlExporter();     
// output file for generated html report
File file = new File(outputFileName);
// setting some sonfigs for the report

exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(filedReport));

SimpleHtmlExporterOutput exporterOutput = new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(file);
// the folder for storing images. It will be subfolder with name starting like generated html and ended with postfix "_files"
File resourcesDir = new File(file.getParent(), file.getName() + "_files");      
// argument ({0}) will be replaced with the real image name
String imageURI = "qip?srvAction=ReportImage&img="+returnFileName.substring(3).replace("/", "%2F")+"_files"+"%2F" + "{0}";

exporterOutput.setImageHandler(new FileHtmlResourceHandler(resourcesDir, imageURI));
exporter.setExporterOutput(exporterOutput);

SimpleHtmlExporterConfiguration exporterConfig = new SimpleHtmlExporterConfiguration();
exporterConfig.setBetweenPagesHtml("");
exporter.setConfiguration(exporterConfig);


SimpleHtmlReportConfiguration reportConfig = new SimpleHtmlReportConfiguration();
reportConfig.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows(true);
exporter.setConfiguration(reportConfig);
```

Comment: Empty space between rows could mean there's an issue with the template design. Can we see some sample JRXML?

Comment: I want to set up no page break for html format as follow: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/nopagebreak/

Comment: See if setting `Ignore Pagination` in the template design works for you.

Comment: Hi it works well. But reportConfig.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows(true); not working. I need set up this parameter.

Comment: I have many reports and I don't want to manually adjusted for each report template.

Comment: The `reportConfig.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows(true);` has no effect because there is no support for it in the `HtmlExporter`. You can see that [here](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jasperreports/blob/master/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/HtmlExporter.java#L314).

Comment: Thanks Narcis, Is there any alternative?

Comment: You could batch update your report templates and set the `Ignore Pagination` flag using a `ReportUpdater` and specific `ant` tasks from the `JasperReports` project. More info [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/antupdate/index.html#antupdate).

Comment: I need a function with similar functionality reportConfig.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows(true); not only set up no page break.